# Grails :No Datastore Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Tags: grails

When I upgraded Grails 2.0.4 to Grails 2.3.0 . The following is stack trace:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI : /InProfile/login/login

Class:java.lang.IllegalStateException



Message:No Datastore Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here



Around line 17 of grails-app\controllers\com\inprofile\common\webtier\controllers\LoginController.groovy

14:    
15: Entity entity = Entity.findByLoginIdAndPassword(params.loginId, params.password);
16:     if(entity){
17:         session.entityId = entity?.entityId
18:         session.entityName = entity?.entityName
19:         session.roleType = entity?.roleType?.roleTypeId
20:         if(Constants.INVESTOR_ROLE_TYPE.equals(session.roleType)) {


Trace

   Line | Method<p>
->> 149 | doGetSession      in org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   141 | getCurrentSession in org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore<br>
|   239 | doCall . . . . .  in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer$_registerAssociationIdentifierGetter_closure6<br>
|    17 | login             in LoginController.groovy<br>
|   886 | runTask . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker<br>
|   908 | run               in     ''<br>
^   662 | run . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```